# Error with SqlCommand and multi-line comments

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlcommand

I'm having a strange error using dotnet `SqlCommand`.

Basically I'm executing a command text that has a multi-line comment with a `GO` in there ex:

```
/*IF OBJECT_ID ( 'dbo.xxx', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[xxx]
GO 
*/

select * from dbo.abc
```

The error that I got was **"Missing end comment mark '*/'"**

I was able to narrow down the error and it seems that the problem is related with the `GO`. If I remove the `G`O It works.

If I execute this command and watch the executed query in sql profile I get:

```
/*IF OBJECT_ID ( 'dbo.xxx', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[xxx]
```

So part of the query wasn't executed... and end comment mark is missing

I've search to see if anyone was having this problem as I've saw this post on msdn with a similar `GO` problem...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7e5ef20d-4b19-4930-9b1f-64304e6987e2/missing-end-comment-mark?forum=sqlreplication

am I the only one with this problem? Is there a workaround?

Comment: What is the point of passing comments into a query you're running through SQLCommand? I understand when you've saved a stored procedure to the server, but I don't understand the point here.

Comment: We have a tool that it's able to deploy sql scripts to databases. Basically instead of using tool A to deploy to SQL Server, Tool B to deploy to Oracle, Tool C to deploy to mysql, etc... what we have is one tool that it's able to do thing like db versioning, deploy to "any" db engine, etc... To deploy sql code to a db we create a DbCommand and execute the script. Sometimes the script contains comments with GO string.

Comment: Well, don't out GO inside the comment, don't know what other solution you're expecting.

Answer (score 4):

I fail to see the point, but the problem is the `GO`. `GO` is not Transact-SQL, it's a batch separator for tools like SSMS. Try it without the `GO` (or without a multi-line comment, or any comment, in the first place).

Comment: I know that the problem is with the GO. What I don't know is why it's being interpreted inside a comment.

Comment: Because it's being parsed first, before the comment.